# If two table values match up, see if value is present?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have two tables:

```
Temp           Snow
--------       -------------
School         School   Skip
--------       -------------
School 1       School 1    1
School 2       School 4    0
School 3       School 3    1
```

And I want to see if a `0` is present in the `Skip` column of table `Snow`, is it possible to just in the rows that contain the same `School` value? In this case, it would just search for a `0` in the `School 3` and `School 1` rows, because the `School` name matches up with the one from `Temp`.

Currently, I am using the following, but it's including every row:

```
SELECT Skip FROM Snow WHERE Skip = 0
```

Comment: so, what will be your desired result then?

Comment: In this case, there would be nothing. But if there was `School 5` in both `Temp` and `Snow`, with a `Skip` value of `0`, then it would `SELECT` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join both tables. As you can see there are letters after the table names. They are called `ALIAS`es (*nickname*) of the tables.

```
SELECT  a.School
FROM    Snow a
        INNER JOIN Temp b
            ON a.School = b.School
WHERE   a.skip = 0
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/282f9/1)

Comment: What do the variables a and be represent here?

Comment: they are called `ALIAS`es (*or nicknames*). they help you minimize your query by instead of writing longer tables names, you can just use them.

Comment: a and b are aliases.. http://www.chapter31.com/2008/08/22/mysql-alias-just-like-table-names-are-case-sensitive-on-nix/

Comment: @Charlie i have added *school 5* as what you mentioned in your comment.